# Is there a way I can pause my iteration loop based on conditions and when those conditions are not true anymore the loop starts where it left off?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, iteration

So right now, I'm trying to like set a pauseloop variable which is initally set to false and when the if block : (ElseIf (i And j = 5) Or (i And j = 6) Or (i And j = 7) Then) arrives the pauseloop then equals true and the iteration stays the same until i and j are equals to 8.. Can anyone help me ?

```
Sub FillDiagonal()


    '##################### DEFINING VARIABLES AND DIM #####################

    ' Call the ClearTable subroutine to clear all data rows from the table
    Call ClearRange
    
    'Define i  as an integer
    Dim i      As Integer
    
    'Define j  as an integer
    Dim j      As Integer
    
    Dim pauseloop As Boolean
    
    pauseloop = False
    
    
    
    
    
    '############################### 2H PAR JOUR ###############################
    
    
    If Range("y4") = 2 Then
        
        ' Loop from row 8 to row 38 with step 2 because 2 shifts per block
        For k = 8 To 38 Step 2
            
            
            'Initialize loop that goes from i to 10 staring at 1
            For i = 1 To 16
                
                
                
                'Initialize loop that goes from j to 10 staring at 1
                For j = 1 To 16
                    
                    'If row = column (make it diagonal)
                    If i = j Then
                        
                        If k Mod 12 = 10 Then
                            
                            'contrainte de 2h pour le poste 6200 et 1600
                            If (i And j = 3) Then
                                Cells(k, "E").offset(i - 2 + (i - 1), j - 1).Value = "VIP"
                                
                            ElseIf (i And j = 4) Then
                                Cells(k, "E").offset(i - 3 + (i - 1), j - 1).Value = "VIP"
                                
                                
                                'Find a way to stop the loop when this happens !!!!!!!!
                            ElseIf (i And j = 5) Or (i And j = 6) Or (i And j = 7) Then
                                pauseloop = True
                                Cells(k, "E").offset(i - 2 + (i - 1), j - 1).Value = ""
                                
                                
                            Else
                                Cells(k, "E").offset(i - 2 + (i - 1), j - 1).Resize(2).Value = "VIP"
                                
                            End If

                        ElseIf (i And j = 3) Then
                            Cells(k, "E").offset(i - 2 + (i - 1), j - 1).Value = "H3"
                            
                        ElseIf (i And j = 4) Then
                            Cells(k, "E").offset(i - 3 + (i - 1), j - 1).Value = "H3"
                            
                        ElseIf (i And j = 5) Or (i And j = 6) Or (i And j = 7) Then
                            pauseloop = True
                            Cells(k, "E").offset(i - 2 + (i - 1), j - 1).Value = ""
                            
                        Else
                            'fills the diagonals cells with "H3" when the if is true
                            Cells(k, "E").offset(i - 2 + (i - 1), j - 1).Resize(2).Value = "H3"
                        End If
                    End If
                Next j
            Next i
        Next k
    
    
    '############################### 1.5H PAR JOUR ###############################
ElseIf Range("y4") = 0.5 Then
    
    ' Loop from row 8 to row 38 with step 2 because 2 shifts per block
    For k = 8 To 38 Step 2
        
        'Initialize loop that goes from i to 10 staring at 1
        For i = 1 To 16
            
            'Initialize loop that goes from j to 10 staring at 1
            For j = 1 To 16
                
                'If row = column (make it diagonal)
                If i = j Then
                    
                    'contrainte de 2h pour le poste 6200 et 1600
                    If (i And j = 3) Or (i And j = 4) Then
                        Cells(k, "E").offset(i - 2 + (i - 1), j - 1).Value = "H3"
                        
                        
                    ElseIf (i And j = 5) Or (i And j = 6) Or (i And j = 7) Then
                        Cells(k, "E").offset(i - 2 + (i - 1), j - 1).Value = ""
                        
                    ElseIf k Mod 8 = 0 Then
                        'fills the diagonals cells with "H3" when the if is true
                        Cells(k, "E").offset(i - 2 + (i - 1), j - 1).Resize(2).Value = "H3"
                        
                    Else
                        Cells(k, "E").offset(i - 2 + (i - 1), j - 1).Resize(2).Value = ""
                        
                        
                        If k Mod 12 = 10 Then
                            Cells(k, "E").offset(i - 2 + (i - 1), j - 1).Resize(2).Value = "VIP"
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    Next k
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
End If



'ElseIf Range("y4") = 1 Then
'For k = 7 To 38

'ElseIf Range("y4") = 0.5 Then
'For k = 7 To 38

End Sub

Sub ClearRange()
    Range("e7:v38").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: You can just add an `If` statement that uses `Stop` - `If x=2 Then Stop`

Comment: If (i And j = 3) is the same as If (i<>0 and j = 3) which because i is 1 to 16 is the same as if (j = 3) which is all you need because you have already tested for i=j.

Comment: not sure i understant your answers.. maybe ill try to ask my question a different way : when the condition (ElseIf (i And j = 5) Or (i And j = 6) Or (i And j = 7) Then is True its actually because those rows and columns are not to be filled in the table but the thing is even tho they are not being filled the loop continues (as it should). I want it to understand that when this condition is filled, the outer loop k=8 to 38, stops and only restarts to loop when the condition is not true anymore

Comment: I'm guessing you need to replace the `For k = 8 To 38 ... Next` with a `Do .. Loop Until` block [see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doloop-statement) so you can control whether to increment k or not.